# Why does the vector-icon not appear?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have an icon in the header of the HomePage but the icon does not appear, only a white X. What should I do?

```
function HomePage({navigation}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Menu')}>
          <Icon name="accessibility" color="white" />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      ),
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "black"
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you update your android/app/build.gradle file and link the fonts?

Comment: You could also try adding type="MaterialIcons" into the Icon tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding on `/app/build.gradle`
apply from: `"../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`
and then rebuild the application and uninstall the app from phone and reinstall again.

Sorry the previous answer was for `expo` users.

Comment: "Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined. Check the  render method of HeaderSegment in TouchableWithoutFeedback."

Imported as "import  { MaterialIcons }  from 'react-native-elements';"